# Hystrix Synchronous usage

Tags: rx-java, observable, blocking, nonblocking, hystrix

Which is better `HystrixCommand.observe()` or `HystrixCommand.execute()` for a synchronous invocation of REST api through Hystrix? 
 If returning an Observable is preferred, then is it better to use blocking (`toBlocking().single()`) or non-blocking (`.subscribe()`) way to read the data?

Answer (score 0):

HystrixCommand.execute() is used for synchronous execution & HystrixCommand.observe() is used for asynchronous execution(returns Observable) as per the hystrix [doc](https://netflix.github.io/Hystrix/javadoc/index.html?com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.html).